# How can I draw a tikzpicture with various holes like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a tikzpicture like the one below? I'm having trouble drawing both the rectangle (display) and rounded rectangle (earpiece speaker) holes. My idea is to make them completely transparent so that the background color is seen through them.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={shape=rectangle,rounded corners,fill=white}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \fill[blue](-5,-5)rectangle(5,5); % background
 \filldraw[fill=white,rounded corners=0.5cm](-2,-4)rectangle(2,4) % phone case
    [sharp corners](-1.75,-3)rectangle(1.75,3) % display
    (0,-3.5)circle(0.25cm) % button
   [rounded corners=0.125cm](-0.5,3.325)rectangle(0.5,3.625); %earpiece speaker
 % Picture labels
 \draw[ultra thick](0,0)--(-30:4)node[mystyle]{Not blue}[ultra thick]--(0,3.5);
 \draw[ultra thick](0,-3.5)--(210:4)node[mystyle]{Blue};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: You can use `even odd rule` as shown by @marmot, but you can also invert the circle orientation by `{[xscale=-1]circle(0.25cm)}`. Here `xscale` works because the coordinate is`(0,...)`, in general it is more tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `even odd rule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={shape=rectangle,rounded corners,fill=white}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \fill[blue](-5,-5)rectangle(5,5); % background
 \filldraw[fill=white,rounded corners=0.5cm,even odd rule](-2,-4)rectangle(2,4) % phone case
    [sharp corners](-1.75,-3)rectangle(1.75,3) % display
    (0,-3.5)circle(0.25cm) % button
   [rounded corners=0.125cm](-0.5,3.325)rectangle(0.5,3.625); %earpiece speaker
 % Picture labels
 \draw[ultra thick](0,0)--(-30:4)node[mystyle]{Now blue}[ultra thick]--(0,3.5);
 \draw[ultra thick](0,-3.5)--(210:4)node[mystyle]{Blue};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]